# Symfony2 LexikFormFilterBundle: Empty values for filter_entity cause form errors

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the [LexikFormFilterBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle) (current dev-version) with Symfony 2.7.0-BETA1. It works as expected, but…

### The Problem

all `filter_entity` fields throw form errors, when the empty option is submitted (i.e. no entity is selected). It is documented [in the basic example](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/working-with-the-bundle.md#i-simple-example), that one has to set

> 'validation_groups' => array('filtering') // avoid NotBlank() constraint-related message

But in my case, the ManyToOne Entities don't use a `NotBlank()`-Assert. Despite this, the form throws errors about non existant entities `''`. When I select an entity, the filter filters correctly and no error message appears. Other filter field types also don't throw errors, when they are empty.

Here is a stripped down representation of my code:

#### Entity code:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Serviceevent.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Serviceevent
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="serviceevents")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ServiceeventRepository")
 */
class Serviceevent
{
    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Park
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Park", inversedBy="serviceevents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="park_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $park;
}
```

#### Form filter code:

```
<?php
// /src/AppBundle/Filter/ServiceeventFilterType.php
namespace AppBundle\Filter;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ServiceeventFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('park', 'filter_entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Park',
                'property' => 'identifyingName',
                'label' => 'Park',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'required' => false,
            ));
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'serviceevent_filter';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'csrf_protection'   => false,
            'validation_groups' => array('filtering'), // avoid NotBlank() constraint-related message
        ));
    }
}
```

### What I expect

I expect, that with no value selected, no filtering for that field happend without an error thrown.

### What I get

Instead, I get form errors for all entity-fields like this one:

> **Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation**
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[park] =
>
> Caused by:
>
> **Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException**
>   Unable to reverse value for property path "[park]": The choice "" does not exist or is not unique
>
> Caused by:
>
> **Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException**
>   The choice "" does not exist or is not unique

### Question is

The question is: how do I get rid of those errors?

Comment: Seems as if this is due to a bug in Symfony 2.7.0-BETA1, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14393 *[2.7] [Form] Regression on non required ChoiceType handling #14393*

I'll have a closer look to it and give feedback here, it this is solved or simply not my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User wcluijt's fix in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14393#issuecomment-94996862 fixed this for me. This confirms, that my problem here was provoked by a Bug in Symfony 2.7.0-BETA1. So wo can close this question as fixed. Sorry for wasting your time with a beta-related bug.